# Logs appear to have switched off?

Tags: linux, eee-pc, syslog

[image]

I'm running a ASUS EEE 701 laptop with the stock linux OS.

I was (and still am) having problems with a cron not running - so I went to look at the logs - and it turns out that none of the logs have been updated in a little while (see picture) - the time is still correct - any idea why the logs aren't updating (and possibly thus the cron)?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that `syslog` daemon is not running as well. Try `ps -A` command in terminal window to see a full list of all running processes